# Scala type inference with function types

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-inference

Consider the following piece of code : (see below for the actual code that needs solving)

```
def applyAll[T,S, U <: Seq[T => S]](l : U, x: T) = l.map(f => f(x))
val u = List((i: Int) => i + 1, (i: Int) => i + 2)
println(applyAll(u,1))
```

(given a `Seq` of `T => S` and a value, we expect to get the funtions applied on this value).

Although `applyAll` compiles fine, calling it on `u` gives the following error :

```
Error:(35, 13) inferred type arguments [Int,Nothing,List[Int => Int]] do not conform to method applyAll's type parameter bounds [T,S,U <: Seq[T => S]]
println(applyAll(u,1))
        ^
```

Which indicates that the compiler can't infer the type parameter `S`, which I'm guessing is because it is 'nested' inside a function type `T => S`.

---

**Edit:**

The actual code I'm trying to fix is similar (albeit complicated), and can't be fixed by removing the U parameter. Here goes :

```
def applyNatural[T, S, Repr <: TraversableLike[T => S, Repr], That]
(data: T, jobs: Repr)
(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, S, That]): That = {
  jobs.map(f => f(data))
}
val u = List((i: Int) => i + 1, (i: Int) => i + 2)
val v = applyNatural(1, u)
println(v)
```

Comment: I see two problems with the edit code: First, Repr is cyclic. To resolve Repr you must look up Repr. Second, there is no build from.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I'm looking to create a function which can apply a collection of functions to a value, and return a collection of values of the same type.

Comment: So input is Collection of functions and a value of type T and it should return collection of T?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `Repr` a higher-kinded type `Repr[_]`, and make the `jobs` argument have the type `Repr[T => S]`:

```
def applyNatural[T, S, Repr[A] <: TraversableLike[A, Repr[A]], That]
  (data: T, jobs: Repr[T => S])
  (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr[T => S], S, That]
): That = {
  jobs.map(f => f(data))
}
```

Comment: That works ! I also managed with def applyNatural[T, S, U <: Traversable[T => S], That](data: T, jobs: Traversable[T => S,U])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[U, S, That]): That ; but your solution is better

Answer (score 4):

The `U` is simply useless. Just write

```
  def applyAll[T,S](l :  Seq[T => S], x: T) = l.map(f => f(x))
  val u = List((i: Int) => i + 1, (i: Int) => i + 2)
  println(applyAll(u,1))
```

Comment: thanks, that works for the given code, although it doesn't solve the problem I'm actually trying to solve (I oversimplified a bit) - I've updated the question with my actual problem